# How can I reference a standalone OpenCV installation inspite of having other version of Opencv version in ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, installation, multiple-instances, ros

I have ROS in the system and it comes with opencv2.4.2. I have also installed opencv from sourceforge.net which is opencv2.4.8 following samontab blog.

Now I have a source code which when run automatically selects the opencv2.4.2. I want the program to run using opencv2.4.8.

I tried adding this to CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories("/home/sai/workspace/opencv-2.4.8/include/opencv") 
   link_directories("/home/sai/workspace/opencv-2.4.8/lib") 
   set(OpenCV_LIBS 
"opencv_gpu;opencv_contrib;opencv_legacy;opencv_objdetect;opencv_calib3d;opencv_features2d;opencv_video;opencv_highgui;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_flann;opencv_core") 

find_package(OpenCV 2.4.8 REQUIRED) 

target_link_libraries(exec {OpeCV_LIBS})
```

But still it uses Opencv that comes with ROS and also gives an error like this

```
             from /home/sai/workspace/loop_detector_on_depth_images/depth_loops/generic/src/dbow/FBit.h:5,
             from /home/sai/workspace/loop_detector_on_depth_images/depth_loops/generic/src/dbow/FBit.cpp:1:
```

/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h: In member function ‘void cvflann::lsh::LshTable::add(cvflann::Matrix)’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h:196:14: error: ‘use_speed_’ was not declared in this scope

and

`pkg-config --cflags opencv` says

`-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its solved.

From the link http://answers.ros.org/question/61923/how-to-use-newer-versions-of-opencv-in-fuerte/

I cheated and went to /opt/ros/fuerte/include and changed the name of opencv2 to opencv2bak. This way it finds the right includes. I don't think it's the right way to do it, though.

Also, went to /opt/ros/fuerte/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake and edited the Install path variable to /usr/local (where I installed)